# Catch double tap events on new Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have an app with a ViewSwitcher that has a MapView (v1) and another View and using a GestureDetector I can detect double taps and switch between the 2 views.

Now I'm trying to switch the app to the new [Google Maps Android API V2](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html) and I have the problem that the GestureDetector set on the MapView no longer reacts to double taps, instead the map is zooming in. Does anyone know how to change that behaviour?

I'm working with the raw `MapView` class, not the Map fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a way now. I have to create a sub class of `MapView` (which is actually a `ViewGroup`) and implement `interceptTouchEvent()` there to detect and catch double taps.

How this is implemented in detail is explained here: [Double Tap -> Zoom on Android MapView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691235/double-tap-zoom-on-android-mapview/12646465#12646465)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and according to: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html), you can set to the `GoogleMap` object (and also to the `MapView`) click and long click listener. So I think you can't set a double click listener.

But you can try this:

```
GoogleMap map=mapView.getMap();
map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```

And maybe it will react to your GestureDetector.

Comment: I tried that now, and it disables zoom gestures but double tap still does not work. Also setZoomGesturesEnabled(false) also disables pinch-zoom which I would like to keep.